# Is it possible to refresh LiveData created by delegation?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `LiveData` which is created by delegation, it is list of objects loaded form REST API Service. Now I want to refresh that list (request api for new list). Here is my code

```
class SomeViewModel(itemsRespository: ItemsRepository): ViewModel(){

    val items by ItemsDelegate(itemsRepository)

    fun refreshItems(){
        //todo refresh items
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to run a refresh every X seconds?

Comment: @KristyWelsh Nope, I just want to call `refreshItems()` method on user interaction (click the button or swipe, it doesn't matter right now)

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't update `LiveData`. You would need `MutableLiveData`. So make sure `ItemsDelegate(itemsRepository)` returns `MutableLiveData`.
2. Call `items.value = <new value>` or `items.postValue(<new value>)`. to update the value of your live data.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But can I reuse ItemsDelegate to update value. Something like this `items.value = ItemsDelegate(itemsRepository)`

Comment: Sure. You just need to create such a method.